# get full image URL from magento 2.0 in iOS

Tags: ios, http, magento

http://mymagentohost.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/(productID)/media

This url is used to get the media for a particular product.

The response does not have the full image URL.

Response:

```
{
    "id": 14,
    "media_type": "image",
    "label": "",
    "position": 1,
    "disabled": false,
    "types": [
      "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "file": "/p/w/pwp_sheet2.jpeg"
  }
```

I am trying to access this URL from a ios app.

Answer (score 0):

Jus add this prefix to the URL in the API response: http://192.168.1.180/magento/pub/media/catalog/product/

Answer (score 0):

If you need the complete path of the images with Magento 2 cache system through API, you can create your custom API based on the native one.

You can based on my answer here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123447/magento-2-rest-api-get-thumbnail-image-url

The important part is to emulate the fronted area in order to generate the correct image URL.

```
\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $helperFactory,

$this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

$image = $this->helperFactory->create()->init($product, $imageId)
        ->constrainOnly(true)
        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
        ->keepTransparency(true)
        ->keepFrame(false)
        ->resize(200, 300);

$this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```